# C#.NET How to add a hyperlink in a reportviewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer, hyperlink

How can i put a hyperlink in a report which refers to page.aspx?id='Fields!RelativePath.Value' ? I have set the EnableHyperlink property to true.

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401664/can-reportviewer-render-a-hyperlink-with-a-relative-path).

EDIT:
As an example, on a TextBox:
Right Click > Properties > Navigation > Jump to URL
This should be set to:   ="page.aspx?id=" & Fields!RelativePath.Value

If it's not working, it may be because of relative path issues.
I'd suggest using System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory to construct the absolute URL to wherever you're trying to get to.

Comment: Can help me further? Because i don't know how to do this: "adding a custom code that retrieves the relative path then concantenate with the field values that you may wish to be part of the URL"

Comment: Thnx, but when i try: =System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "/page.aspx" it doens't work. And the relative path also didn't work.